# Http strange behavior with Headers

Tags: flutter, http-headers

I am using Flutter to connect to an AWS APIGateway.

I making test and I have this extrange behavior:

First I connect without http requests header and all is OK:

```
final response = await client.get(apiURL);
```

Now i need to add some security like a a api-key, but then I have a Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

```
    Map<String, String> apiHeader = {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "accept": "application/json"
            "x-api-key" =  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    };

    final response =await client.get(apiURL,headers: apiHeader);
```

Then, I get error:

```
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:51642/dart_sdk.js:4342:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:51642/dart_sdk.js:37882:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51642/dart_sdk.js:37876:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51642/dart_sdk.js:37708:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51642/dart_sdk.js:37714:13)
at http://localhost:51642/dart_sdk.js:33226:9
```

On the server side, now I have not api-key activate yet. Just I am trying add headers befores add security..

Don't mind the header I add, with all of them I get the same error...
Any idea? I am very obfuscated about this error...
Thanks a lot¡

EDITED:
I have fixed the map syntax, but  have the same http error:

```
Map<String, String> apiHeader = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'x-api-key' :  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues.

Here is a fixed Map

```
    Map<String, String> apiHeader = {
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'accept': 'application/json',
     'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
    };
```

- First, the map syntax is {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}. No equal "=" signs.
- Second, to split entries use ",", not ";"
- Third prefer using single quotes when dealing with Strings.

Comment: Sorry, I made this error writing de post. But I have the same error with this header:

Map<String, String> apiHeader = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'x-api-key' :  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };

Thanks¡¡

Comment: Have you tried your request in Postman? Does it work?
Maybe you need to provide additional headers for AWS (will edit my answer)

Comment: I have solved the problem. I need to avail CORS in the server (API Gateway).
Here more info: https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html
Thanks¡

Answer (score 0):

You might be just missing a comma after the 2nd line of your header object creation:

```
    Map<String, String> apiHeader = {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "accept": "application/json",
            "x-api-key":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    };

    final response =await client.get(apiURL,headers: apiHeader);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what you try to say:
This line? 
'content-type': 'application/json',

Thanks¡

Comment: Compare your code above to the edited code here as the code you have above is not properly formatted as @kvs states above.

Comment: Ok. I fixed the sintax but already  I get the Error: XMLHttpRequest error when add the header to the requests. If I avoid headers, I connect without problem. Could be some server issue?